# Tooltip using empty hyperlinks

Tags: excel, vba

I've been searching around on how to enable an improvised tooltip. I came across a tutorial where the author managed to do it by using empty hyperlinks. I was able to do this on a single column but I need it on a larger scale. I've come up with a for loop but for some reason I'm getting a mismatch error on my if else statement. Here it is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim IdentityRow As Long
    Dim SpecialIdentifier As String
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = Sheets("Dashboard")

    For IdentityRow = 15 To 3000
    SpecialIdentifier = CStr(ws1.Range("B" & IdentityRow).Value)


    If SpecialIdentifier = "Rehire" Then

         ws1.Range("B" & IdentityRow).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws1.Range("B" & IdentityRow).Value, _
         Address:=" ", _
         ScreenTip:="User is a rehire, please remember to check HRI for current LM details", _
         TextToDisplay:=ws1.Range("B" & IdentityRow).Value


         ws1.Range("B" & IdentityRow).Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
         ws1.Range("B" & IdentityRow).Font.Underline = black

      End If

   Next IdentityRow
End Sub
```

This is where I'm getting the mismatch issue:

```
ws1.Range("B" & IdentityRow).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws1.Range("B" & IdentityRow).Value, _
Address:=" ", _
ScreenTip:="User is a rehire, please remember to check HRI for current LM details", _
TextToDisplay:=ws1.Range("B" & IdentityRow).Value
```

any ideas? basically i want to convert all entries in a row to an empty hyperlink just for the sake of getting tooltip.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Hi @user2519726, does my answer below address your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The Anchor argument that you provide to Hyperlinks.Add should be a Range, not a Value. Try:

```
Anchor:=ws1.Range("B" & IdentityRow)
```

instead of:

```
Anchor:=ws1.Range("B" & IdentityRow).Value
```

You'll also need to correct `ws1.Range("B" & IdentityRow).Font.Underline = black` to `ws1.Range("B" & IdentityRow).Font.Color = black` to get the code to run.